# Full-text search with german umlauts

Tags: sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I created a table using German (Germany) as the Full-text language, in the settings I tried setting accent sensitivity to both sensitive and insensitive. I, however, get following odd results.

The table contains the following entries:

- Müller - Muller - Mueller
- Luginbühl - Luginbuhl - Luginbuehl

Executing following search

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Search WHERE CONTAINS(CNameCombined, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL,  "Mueller")')
```

I get these results: Müller, Muller, Mueller

Executing a similar search

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Search WHERE CONTAINS(CNameCombined, 'FORMSOF (INFLECTIONAL,  "Luginbuehl")')
```

I get zero results.

Does anyone have an idea what the reason for this behavior might be? It seems to work for some words, but not for all of them.

I'm running a SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server 2012.

Comment: When you set the collation type did you re-load the data? Collation changes don't affect extant data.

Answer (score 1):

I think all you need to know is listed here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx Look for the right languages in the index and the query parser (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx#Additional_Considerations).
...and check/post your params